# Can a web-filter track my internet access over application API calls?

Tags: encryption, web-service, data-leakage

I'm at college where each student has a login ID and password for internet access through the CyberRoam web filter for blocking certain websites.

My question is, when I'm browsing Facebook, YouTube, or Wikipedia through their respective mobile apps on my phone, can the CyberRoam client track what I'm viewing through the application's API calls? How does this compare to the data collected by CyberRoam when I browse the internet through my computer's web browser?

Answer (score 1):

If your connection is https:// rather than http://, CyberRoam should not be able to see the content you are viewing.  It will just know the website.

If your connection is http://, anyone can view your content, not just CyberRoam.

Facebook, Youtube, and Wikipedia all use https://  by default.  So the content on the three example sites you listed should look like gibberish to CyberRoam.

If you want to get around the filter they use to block websites, use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Web traffic is filtered through the CyberRoam appliance and the administrator can see those requests.  The product has no knowledge of whether a browser is making those requests or some other software using an API call.  This is assuming your phone is using the college's internet and not your own data plan.